# Regex for matching python decorators

Tags: python, regex, decorator

I use nano as my editor, and I recently added a few syntax highlighting configurations, of which one of them highlights python code. However, one thing that I noticed is that it doesn't highlight decorators. What would be the regex for it?

Note that the actual regex is in bash form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be fairly safe matching anything that is not a comment or string where the `@` symbol is the first non-whitespace character on a line. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fairly safe matching anything that is not a comment or string where the `@` symbol is the first non-whitespace character on a line. So

```
@[[:alnum:]]+
```

seems OK to me as long as strings are defined *after* it.